# Creation of a Singleton object in initializer list causes an Access Violation (only Release Mode)

Tags: c++, singleton, release, access-violation

I do see a (for me) strange Access Violation exception. I'll try to reduce the problem as much as possible. I have a class A and a singleton object sing_. The code looks somehow like that:

```
class A {
    A();
    Sing& sing_;
}

A::A() : sing_(Sing::instance()){
    call a method that creates a local copy of Singleton Sing.
    ....
}
```

The class Sing inherits from Singleton:

```
class Sing : public Singleton<Sing>{
    friend class Singleton<Sing>;
    ....
}
```

Singleton itself looks like that (this is the implementation in the QuantLib library)

```
template <class T>
class Singleton : private boost::noncopyable {
  public:
    static T& instance();
  protected:
    Singleton() {}
};


template <class T>
T& Singleton<T>::instance() {
    static std::map<Integer, boost::shared_ptr<T> > instances_;
    #if defined(QL_ENABLE_SESSIONS)
    Integer id = sessionId();
    #else
    Integer id = 0;
    #endif
    boost::shared_ptr<T>& instance = instances_[id];
    if (!instance)
        instance = boost::shared_ptr<T>(new T);
    return *instance;
}
```

My project code is embedded in a Qt Gui environment. Starting it in Debug mode causes no troubles. Things change horribly when I try to start in Release mode. This is the main method:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    GUI w;
    w.show();
    w.setup(argc, argv);

    return a.exec();
}
```

Finally the class GUI looks abbreviated like that:

```
class GUI : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    GUI(QWidget *parent = 0, Qt::WFlags flags = 0);
    ~GUI();
private:
    boost::shared_ptr<A> a_; 
};
```

When I start this code in Release mode the following happens:

1. A method called ___tmainCRTstartup() is invoked. Therein a method _WinMain is invoked.
2. Inside this method *WinMain (even before the main method is invoked and the GUI object 
   is created) the constructor of A is called. This means that the member sing* is going to be initialized.
3. sing_ is initialized during the call of Sing::instance(). Everything looks fine so far.
4. The constructor of A is executed. Therein a local refernce to the singleton object Sing is created. Calling Sing::instance() results in an access violation at that line

   ```
       boost::shared_ptr<T>& instance = instances_[id];
   ```

When I look at instances_[id] at that place (debugging in Release mode) the map looks quite destroyed. That means there is one element in the map. But the key is not 0 but a very negativ integer and also the value looks strange.

I have absolutly no idea what goes wrong here.

Changing the member sing_ in A to be a static member fixes the problem:

```
class A {
    A();
    static Sing& sing_;
}

Sing& sing_ = Sing::instance();

A::A() {
    call a method that creates a local copy of Singleton Sing.
    ....
}
```

That's of course nice but I'm really wondering what's the "big" difference between these two implementations. Why does the first way end in an Access Violation? Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Singletons aren't the one true evil, they've got their uses.

Comment: Surely `sessionId` returns some rubbish? PS: worst abuse of the singleton antipattern I've seen so far.

Comment: That it works in debug and not release suggests that you are not initializing variables. Which in turn is causing undefined behavior somewhere else in the code. You do need to fix this problem correctly currently you have just hidden it and it will come back to bite you. Turn up you your compiler warning level; and fix all the warnings (preferably treat all warnings as errors).

Comment: No, QL_ENABLE_SESSIONS is not defined. So this part of the code should be irrelevant.

Comment: @LokiAstari What do you mean with "currently you have just hidden it and it will come back to bite you"? Is the static variant of code just running by chance?

Comment: Don't you have to explicitly instantiate static members? But not doing that would cause a linking error. Or maybe the order of instantiation changes? In debug these are automatically pre-set to 0 but in release they are random values.

Comment: @NicholasSmith Singletons can _always_ be replaced by something better.

Comment: Are you using a multithreaded environment?

Comment: @NicholasSmith yes, for objects available globally and limited to one instance. Which is the case in like 0.0000000001% cases.

Comment: And is that the first time the an instance of Sing is created?

Comment: @SebaStopol: Yes. It depends on the exact problem but what you have done is just delayed the onset of the problem. If something is breaking because of undefined behavior you probably have not solved the problem just moved it.

Comment: @LokiAstari: Sorry for the late response. Meanwhile I have removed most of the warning on Level 4 (VS c++ 2010). The remaining warning are presumably harmless, such as: "warning C4127: conditional expression is constant" or "warning C4189: 'relTolerance' : local variable is initialized but not referenced" or similar stuff. There are tons of warnings coming from the QuantLib, Qt or qwt. Of course I didn't start "fixing" these warnings. But still the same Access violation...

Comment: @SebaStopol: The code you have provided looks good. So it looks like undefined behavior of some other code. Without the code base I can not help further. Note: I set my compiler to treat all warnings as errors so it will not compile with any warnings. Note: You can turn off the warnings for the QT libraries by using `#pragma warning( push )` and `#pragma warning( pop )`. around the includes See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the route of the problem, but I can offer some help in getting there:

First of all, the most common reasons why programs that run in debug fail in release (and vice versa):

1. In debug all memory is usually (most debuggers i know of) initialized as 0. So safety nullptr checks avoid errors. In release the memory isn't initialized, so you get garbage/random values.
2. Timing. Code optimizations, and the lack of debugging checks and settings (like setting everything to 0) make the code faster, so there's a different timing between threads.

Now back to your case. The reason why you see the variables as "destroyed" as you put it, is probably just because of the code optimizations.
Usually if you have code optimizations enabled, the compiler might decide to put some variables in the hardware registers, and not on the stack as they are intended.
This might cause the debugger to misinterpret some local variables. (Most commonly the *this pointer is stored in a register).

Now, the operator[] in a map shouldn't raise an exception. If the map doesn't have a value for that key, then it will be created.

So the only explanation I can think of is that the map itself is corrupt, so while it's trying to iterate through the map's nodes, it crashes.

This type of corruption is usually caused by 2 threads trying to alter the map at the same time.
This is possible in your case because there's no lock protection in that simple singleton implementation.
Another indication that this might be the case, is that when you make it static the problem is solved. Making the variable static causes the initiation of the object to occur much earlier, which might be just the timing you need to solve the threading race.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! This is very interesting. To answer you questions: 1. I'm not using a multithreaded environment... at least my part of the code is not multithreaded. I don't know about Qt or qwt. 2. Yes, this is the first time a instance of Sing is created. Everything seems to be ok, but on the second call of Sing::instance() it crashes. What you wrote about the operator[] sounds very logical. Somehow the map gets "corrupted" after the first initialisation. It is also the case that in the "static" case the Sing::instance() is called earlier.

Comment: Concerning the optimization I also tried a release built without any optimization. The problem remains. Concerning the "timing problem" assumption I also see this behaviour when "debugging" through the code. At least it seems to me to be a purely sequential codeflow in that case. But, as I said the constructor of A is called somewhere in the "WinMain" method. Even before the object is "born" in the main method. I've no idea what happens in the WinMain.